# Faulty algorithm for simultaneous diagonalization?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

I found a simple algorithm for simultaneous diagonalization of two commuting matrices (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2006.16364), which seemed to be well-founded. For commuting matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, this algorithm forms the Jordan decomposition of

$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{A}$,

then constructs

$\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A}$

and its Jordan decomposition,

$\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{T} \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{T} \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{T}$.

The ArXiv paper states that $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{T}$ satisfies

$\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A} $

and

$\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{B} $,

which would be favorable in terms of simultaneous diagonalization.

However, for specific **A** and **B** matrices (see below), I cannot retreive the $\mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A}$ matrix from the $\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U}$ expression. Could you please help me what the problem would be with this algorithm? My Mathematica implementation is the following:

```
A = {{-0.488772, 0.572568, 1.00474, 0.576474, -0.883678}, {0.572568, 
    0.95183, -0.822118, 0.171161, -1.65205}, {1.00474, -0.822118, 
    0.307811, 1.62311, 1.51333}, {0.576474, 0.171161, 
    1.62311, -0.191142, -0.619896}, {-0.883678, -1.65205, 
    1.51333, -0.619896, -0.579727}};

B = {{1.99737, -0.417634, 0.510778, 0.174017, -1.21089}, {-0.417634, 
    2.79806, 0.0333479, 0.278912, -0.402774}, {0.510778, 0.0333479, 
    1.58929, 1.23511, 1.26844}, {0.174017, 0.278912, 1.23511, 
    1.44669, -0.539531}, {-1.21089, -0.402774, 1.26844, -0.539531, 
    1.16859}};

{SA, DA} = JordanDecomposition[A];
T = Inverse[SA] . B . SA;
{ST, DT} = JordanDecomposition[T];
U = SA . ST;
Chop[N[FullSimplify[Inverse[U] . A . U], 5] // MatrixForm]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point where you deviate from the paper is when you compute an arbitrary Jordan decomposition of $T$ using `JordanDecomposition[T]`. (You gloss over this in the text of the question by referring to “its Jordan decomposition” as if this were unique.) You leave it to Mathematica to choose the order of the blocks in the Jordan decomposition of $T$. The paper, by contrast, in Equation $(12)$, constructs a Jordan decomposition of $T$ by building it from Jordan decompositions of the blocks of $T$, thus ensuring that the resulting blocks are consistent with the blocks in the Jordan decomposition of $A$.

Comment: @TobiR: Good question. I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that **A** has four distinct eigenvalues, while **T** has only three diagonal blocks (possibly due to the fact that **B** also contains only three distinct eigenvalues).

Comment: @TobiR: Yes, $T$ (like $B$) only has $3$ distinct eigenvalues. That's not a problem theoretically. What makes this difficult practically is the rounding – technically you don't really have simultaneously diagonalizable matrices. You may have to clamp the small matrix entries to $0$ to get a proper block structure.

Comment: @TobiR: One thing you could try is to apply all $5!$ permutations to $T$ and pick the one that yields $U^{-1}AU$ closest to  $D_A$.

Comment: @TobiR: No, that doesn't help.

Comment: @TobiR: Actually, quite a simple way to simultaneously diagonalize these two matrices (that has nothing to do with the paper, though) is: `F = A + B; {SF, DF} = JordanDecomposition[F]; DA = Inverse [SF] . A . SF; DB = Inverse [SF] . B . SF;`. This will usually work, unless two distinct pairs of eigenvalues happen to add to the same sum, but in that case you can just use $A+\lambda B$ with some $\lambda$ that doesn't cause that problem.

Comment: In the linked question, somebody suggested the use of $\mathbf{A}+t\mathbf{B}$ with a $t\not\in\left\{\frac{\lambda-\lambda'}{\mu-\mu'}:\ \lambda,\lambda'\in\operatorname{spectrum}(A),
\,\mu,\mu'\in\operatorname{spectrum}(B),\,\mu\ne\mu'\right\}$ value. Should this work?

Comment: @TobiR: Ah, you could have saved me a bit of thinking if you'd pointed to that question earlier! Yes, that's correct – you want to make sure that $A+tB$ doesn't have additional degeneracy (over and above the degeneracy it may necessarily inherit from $A$ and $B$, which isn't a problem) – so you want to prevent $\lambda+t\mu=\lambda'+t\mu'$ for $\lambda\ne\lambda'$ eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu\ne\mu'$ eigenvalues of $B$ – that's equivalent to that prescription (with $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$ interchanged).

Comment: And what is the situation if all of the eigenvalues are the same in either A or B, or both?

Comment: @TobiR: That's not a problem. Any space that's an eigenspace of both $A$ and $B$ is also an eigenspace of $A+tB$, regardless of the value of $t$. A problem arises only if the choice of $t$ creates eigenspaces of $A+tB$ that aren't also eigenspaces of both $A$ and $B$. This happens only due to degeneracy newly introduced by an unfortunate choice of $t$, not due to degeneracy already present in $A$ and/or $B$.

Comment: So if I choose $t$ in the following way:

`numer = a[[n]] - a[[1]];
denom = b[[n]] - b[[1]];
If[Min[{numer, denom}] <= tol,
  t = 1.0,
  For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
   gap = b[[i]] - b[[i - 1]];
   If[gap <= tol, Continue[]];
   denom = Min[denom, gap]];
  t = 1.1*numer/denom];`

then should this choice avoid forming new degeneracy? Here $a$ and $b$ denote the vector of eigenvalues in $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Comment: @TobiR: I don't really feel like debugging your Mathematica code :-) Everything mathematical has been said. I don't understand why you only have $a_n-a_1$ there and none of the other differences between eigenvalues of $A$, but perhaps you've sorted it in some way that allows you to do that. I'm sure you'll figure it out.